# Центральная, Восточная и Южная Европа

Tags: прописная-строчная

«Мощности Крымского моста придётся кардинально увеличивать, потому что через него будет идти снабжение китайскими товарами Центральной, Восточной и Южной Европы.»

Верно ли употребление с большой буквы регионов Европы?

Answer (score 1):

Существует экономико-политическое деление Европы на пять регионов: **Западный; Восточный; Северный; Южный; Центральный.** Названия регионов являются именами собственными и пишутся с прописной буквы.

[Регионы европы | author24.ru](https://author24.ru/spravochniki/geografiya/materik_evraziya_geograficheskoe_polozhenie_materika_istoriya_issledovaniya/regiony_evropy/)

Comment: спасибо...А то на меня накинулись в редакции, что еще за Южная Европа, о такой не слышали....

Answer (score 0):

Грамота [пишет](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=271729):

*Есть правило: названия частей государств и континентов, носящие терминологический характер, пишутся с прописной буквы: Западная Европа, Средняя Азия, Центральная Америка.*

[Восточная Европа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0), [Центральная Европа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0), [Южная Европа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0) - названия частей Европы. Как названия, они пишутся с заглавной буквы.

Comment: М_Г, а нужна эта запятая после "как названия"?